# How to target items

Tags: css, web, element, targeting

I have currently a main style sheet, but multiple pages using that sheet, i do not want to make multiple style sheets, as I am using PHP to out put it. How do I target specific elements such as a text area, Like:

```
<div id="regform" class="
<label>Password:</label>
<input name="Password" placeholder="Password"></input>
```

But the css is:

```
input
{
height:100px;
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

That all works FINE! It creates the look I want, but that changes all text areas to look like that, and that is not what I want, I want only text areas in that div to look like that, as I use text areas alot.

Summary:

How do I change the look of textareas and elements in only ONE div? So it does not affect any other text area.

This is an edit! This did not work PLEASE LOOK AT THIS! http://jsfiddle.net/wbyQL/1/

Comment: How about using `classes` ?

Comment: css `class`, `id` etc all serve your purpose. Pls look them up in Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="regform" class="">
<label>Password:</label>
<input name="Password" placeholder="Password"></input>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#regform input
{
height:100px;
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wbyQL/3/

Comment: That did not work.. Nothing happens now, all styling has lost

Comment: THANKS SOO MuCH! Can I ask, why does that work? Why did I not need the > , You have saved me soo much goggling xD Thanks soo much! <3

Comment: It worked as you were using `#regform > input` which will not target any input as `>` is children selector, it selects elements just inside `#regform` which is `form` and not `input`. ` ` (space) is the descendant selector. It will select all `input` tags as long as they are inside `#regform` no mater how many levels inside.

Comment: No problem!.. Yes it worked with the code you gave in your original question because the input was directly after the div. But in your live code it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div id="regform" class="x-div">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input name="Password" placeholder="Password"></input>
</div>
```

css

```
.x-div input {
    height:100px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please look at here and help me, thanks for the responce! http://jsfiddle.net/wbyQL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use selectors. Depending on whether you'd like THAT div or ANY div with a text input to have that css applied to them:

HTML:

```
<div id="regform" class="
<label>Password:</label>
<input name="Password" placeholder="Password"></input>
```

CSS:

```
#regform input
{
height:100px;
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

If you want the css to apply to `input` which is in ANY `div` and not just that one:

```
div input
{
height:100px;
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

I would recommend reading up CSS selectors.

```
#bar div .foo {
 //css stuff
}
```

Basically this means: find an element with the class "foo", which is somewhere inside of a div, where that div is somewhere inside of an element with id = "bar";

Comment: Thanks alot! the other guy just beat you to it, but thanks ALOT! :)

Comment: I would give you a up arrow thingy, but .. I am not a level xD